# Faster way to export data frame as XML in R

Tags: xml, r

I am building a shiny app that helps to download data in various formats, including JSON, CSV and XML, from a data frame.

I am using the write.xml function from XML package, but it takes so long while the CSV and JSON data are downloaded momentarily.

Is there a faster way to write a data frame to XML in R?

Comment: how big are the data frames? I suspect the time is more in the actual download vs the file creation. You could try ensuring the XML file is compressed before serving it (I haven't looked to see if Shiny enables gzip by default).